# How can I put an opening and a closing PHP tag in an echo?

Tags: php, html, echo

I already post this question before but people always ask unnecessary question. I'm gonna explain it in a simple way.

I HAVE **3** files :

1. a php file (contains only html, thats important) : We call it X file for the example.
2. a php file where there's some database query to insert database data on the screen : Y file
3. a php file (a script that will make some manipulations) : Z file

SO, i want to include **Y** into **X** with the script of **Z**.

In **Z**, i make a `str_replace($text, $new, file_get_contents($file));`

The ONLY THING is that i need to include PHP open and close TAGS in **X** because there's no php tags in it.

So, `$new = "<?php include('Y.php'); ?>";`.
If you try, the close tag wont be considered in the string, but that's what i want.

Hope this question is NOW clear. I can't be more clearer than that. :D

Thanks for you advice.

Comment: `<?php echo htmlentities("<?php include('this.php'); ?>"); ?>`

Comment: wasn't there a <code> html tag ?

Comment: @IonutFlaviusPogacian huh? Yes there is, but what's that got to do with this?

Comment: @IonutFlaviusPogacian Because it doesn't do anything to help this situation?

Comment: @IonutFlaviusPogacian You still need to replace the characters.

Comment: You've already asked *this exact question*, and you didn't do any better of a job explaining yourself there than you've done here. Please figure out what you're actually trying to do before asking duplicate questions, you're just going to get the same answers.

Comment: @meager : I redo the question.. suppose to be clear as water : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14986890/how-to-include-a-php-file-in-a-html-file-via-a-php-script

Comment: @Hugo.T stop "redo"ing the question and edit the original one

Comment: @Gareth: U happy now ?..

Comment: @Hugo.T No, because you've still created a duplicate, and your question is still completely unclear. You're asking a nonsense question. What you're trying to do doesn't make sense, and it's based on this fundamentally wrong idea you have that the closing/opening PHP tags inside the string somehow matter. They don't. They cannot affect the PHP tags in the file that is being run.

Comment: @meager: Than.. how can i include a php file in an html file with a php script ?

Comment: You want to evaluate the content of a.php, and place the results into b.html, all from within c.php? No part of this involves echoing a string containing `<?php ?>` tags. From within c.php, read the contents of b.html, and then capture the contents of a.php. Substitute the contents captured from a.php into the proper part of b.html, and send the results to the browser.

Comment: Yes .. and the content of a.php is database query and their results.

Comment: @Hugo.T You're using PHP completely wrongly. Your script should store the results of the database query in a variable, and then render the page using those results. You don't "include the results of a PHP file in an HTML file", you make a PHP file which evaluates the query and then renders the HTML with the results of the query interpolated into it.

Comment: No because i dont just put results.. i put manipulations.
Example of what i have in thhe include file: A select query, the results. 
The c.php is like a batch file to modify files. It will be used only one time. But, the b.html need to do the query everytime it will be refreshed. The results is not static.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to replace the `<` and `>` characters with their HTML entities:

```
<?php echo "&lt;?php include('this.php'); ?&gt;"; ?>
```

If you want to include the file, there's no need for the above, running the code below is more than sufficient:

```
<?php
include('this.php');
?>
```

You don't have to use two lots of PHP tags...

Comment: It will work in the file, but will display <?php include('this.php'); ?> and not the content of the file..

Comment: @Hugo.T What? The content of the file? Aren't you trying to echo the tags only?

Comment: xD Mb he means `eval`?

Comment: Woah! Nice curve ball... If you want to print the contents of the file, why not just include it??

Comment: @Hugo.T Just do `include`. You don't need the php tags for that.

Comment: What i want to do is to insert the content of this.php in a .php file but i need to enter the open and close php file to include it

Comment: @Hugo.T Why? I don't get it. What's inside `this.php`?

Comment: @Antony: Of course i need it because the file that i want to change is a .php file but only contains html (there's no php tag in the file)

Comment: Huh? See my updated answer (I think) :/

Comment: @Hugo.T Just move the `include` out of the enclosing php tags.

Comment: I think he is trying to use html as a php generator.

Comment: @Hugo.T You really aren't explaining yourself well. I *think* you want to generate a working PHP file, which has the `<?php ?>` tags around the *content* of `this.php`? Is that correct? If this is the case, you can't do what you're trying to do with `echo`. PHP won't interpret the stuff being echo'd for you, it's just a string.

Comment: @meagar: I want to include a php file in an html file via a php script.

Comment: Then all you need to do is `<?php include('my_file'); ?>`. There's no need for extra PHP tags or anything like that. Simply including the file will achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I may as well put this as an answer.

If you don't want to manually replace `<` and `>`:

```
<?php echo htmlentities("<?php include('this.php'); ?>"); ?>
```

Comment: It might be worth noting the implications of doing that, though. For example in case he wants double-quotes, etc.