# How to include a php file in a html file via a php script

Tags: php, html, tags, include

I already post this question before but people always ask unnecessary question. I'm gonna explain it in a simple way.

I HAVE **3** files :

1. a php file (contains only html, thats important) : We call it X file for the example.
2. a php file where there's some database query to insert database data on the screen : Y file
3. a php file (a script that will make some manipulations) : Z file

SO, i want to include **Y** into **X** with the script of **Z**.

In **Z**, i make a `str_replace($text, $new, file_get_contents($file));`

The ONLY THING is that i need to include PHP open and close TAGS in **X** because there's no php tags in it.

So, `$new = "<?php include('Y.php'); ?>";`.
If you try, the close tag wont be considered in the string, but that's what i want.

Hope this question is NOW clear. I can't be more clearer than that. :D

Thanks for you advice.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the constraint that requires there be no <? ?> tags in X?

Comment: You should edit the original question to clarify it. Don't keep adding duplicate questions

Comment: If i change it in it, all the comments already in it will be useless, so i closed it

Comment: *Stop* "Redoing" the question. You're expected to *fix* your existing questions, not post a *triplicate* of the same thing.

Comment: You don't need the php open and close tags unless there is php code to interpret. I.e. it can even be an HTML file if you want. In X you can define your own tag, f.e. `{content}` and replace it with the result of your database query. There is template systems like SMARTY that could help you in your task.

Comment: **NO**. As I said on your last questions, which were duplicates of this one, the *closing tag in the string will **not** be considered*. You're completely wrong on this. Your assumptions are completely incorrect, you need to figure out what your problem *actually is* before asking more questions about this.

Answer (score 0):

To include a file you do

```
<?php
include(file);
?>
```

So in this case

X contains `<?php include('Y'); ?>` And Y contains `<?php include('Z') ?>`

But if you are doing what i think you are doing (a template of some sort) you would be better of by looking into overflow buffer ( ob_start and ob_end_flush for example )

Those can place all echoed information into a variable to be modified later, also the php inside is run, instead of just read as text as in your example with the file_get_contents()

Answer (score 0):

The question is very unclear and vague, but I have a guess:

File X is some HTML where you want to replace special markers.
File Y loads the value from DB that should replace the marker.
File Z does the replacement.

This could be solved like that (File Z):

```
<?php
ob_start();
include("Y.php");
$repl = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

ob_start();
include("X.php");
$src = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo str_replace("THEREPLACEMENTMARKER", $repl, $src);
?>
```